# ionic/angularjs - best way to clear data from services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, dependency-injection, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic app (built on Angularjs) and so far so good.  My app contains a logout feature and I'd like to clear data in all services so that when the next user logs in, he will not see the old data.  What is the best way to achieve this?

From what I've read around here and on Google:

1. Its possible to inject $rootScope into each service and have it listen to an event which will clear the data in the service.
2. Have one service which has all the other services injected into it.  Implement a clear() method in each service.  (What if you have 50 services?)

Are there other ways?

Comment: injecting rootScope into a Service is possible and you can listen to events like that and call your service.clean() function.

**But, what datas will you want to clean ?** Can you provide some examples ? 
I assume that your login inits several datas and, after the next login, your data shall be over

Comment: I have many services and each of those services loads (using ng-resource) and holds data for each page in my app (have around 10 or so pages).

Comment: Sorry, but just cannot hold myself - this seems like perfect case to just reload the page.

Comment: Doesn't that only reload single page?

Comment: Looks like $window.location.reload() reloads the entire app.  But from a UX perspective, it doesn't look good.